# UTRAN Cell Identity returned by getCid()

Tags: android

In UMTS I get a large number returned by `getCid()` (larger than the allowed value). Is this the UTRAN Cell Identity (UC-ID)?

```
UC-Id = RNC-Id + C-Id
```

Does someone knows that? How to get the `C-Id` from the `UC-Id`?

Thanks and Best,
Benny

Comment: I think noone is really understand the core of your question, please be more specific

Comment: Okay, in GSM getCid() returns the CellId of the cell. As far I know in UMTS the value that is received includes the identifier of the RNC and the identifier of the cell. This means the long (7-9 digits) number that is returned by getCid() in an UMTS network contains both, but I just want to have the CellId. I think the way is the following: C-Id = UC-Id%65536 and  RnC-Id = (UC-Id)-(C-Id)/65536. Or why is the returned value in UMTS a number that is bigger then 65536, which is the max allowed value if the android documentation is correct.

Answer (score 6):

The RNC id is the first 2 bytes of the 4 byte Cell Id (3GPP 25.401, section 6.1.5), if the network type is UMTS/HSxPA/HSPA+." 
 I have access to an operator network and I checked in the system and it's true and correct.

 Based on that please see my code how you can easily get RNCID + CID:
Convert CID to ByteArray:

```
    public static byte[] convertByteArray__p(int p_int){
    byte[] l_byte_array = new byte[4];
    int MASK_c = 0xFF;
    for (short i=0; i<=3; i++){
        l_byte_array[i] = (byte) ((p_int >> (8*i)) & MASK_c);
    }
    return l_byte_array;
}
```

Get the RNCID and CID:

```
    public int getRNCID_or_CID__p(byte[] p_bytes, short p_which){
    int MASK_c = 0xFF;
    int l_result = 0;   
    if (p_which == Constants.CID_C) {
        l_result = p_bytes[0] & MASK_c ;
        l_result = l_result + ((p_bytes[1] & MASK_c ) << 8);
    } else if (p_which == Constants.RNCID_C){
        l_result = p_bytes[2] & MASK_c ;
        l_result = l_result + ((p_bytes[3] & MASK_c ) << 8);
    } else { 
        g_FileHandler.putLog__p('E', "getRNCID_or_CID__p invalid parameter");
    }
    return l_result;     
}
```

Than you can easily call like this:

```
        byte[] l_byte_array = new byte[4];
        l_byte_array = convertByteArray__p(l_cid);
        int l_RNC_ID   = getRNCID_or_CID__p(l_byte_array,Constants.RNCID_C);
        int l_real_CID = getRNCID_or_CID__p(l_byte_array,Constants.CID_C);
```

Constants RNCID_C(1) and CID_C(2) are only contants just for me to seperate which parameter will be passed through.

Answer (score 4):

If CID is > 65536, it's not actually the cell-ID, but a linear combination of the real cell-ID and RNC-ID:

```
UTRAN_CELL_ID = RNCID x 65536 + CellID
```

To extract the cellID, use the modulo operation:

```
CellID = UTRAN_CELL_ID % 65536
```

To extract the RNCID, get the integer part:

```
RNCID = UTRAN_CELL_ID / 65536
```

Comment: RNCID should be equal to (UTRAN_CELL_ID - UTRAN_CELL_ID%65536)/65536

Answer (score 3):

try 
(cell id % 65536)
it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is more simple than this. Cell ID is in the low register of the value getCid() returns, the RNC is the high register of this value (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getCid()).
So:

> getCid() == RNC << 16 | CID
>
> CID = getCid() & 0xffff
>
> RNC = (getCid() >> 16) & 0xffff