# cell id greater than 0xffff

Tags: android

I am recently working on a android project where I need to get the CELL Id and LAC (location Area Code) and wnen i run this in my device i get a value greater than the default max value of `0xffff` for **CELL Id**

why is this happening ? Does 3G and 2G make any difference?

This is my code

```
TextView msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)

getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
        final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            msg.setText("LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid());
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value you get?

Comment: CELL id : 6768231 and  LAC :31032

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421376/10095046) is the answer.

As explained in [ETSI TS 125 401](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/125400_125499/125401/04.02.00_60/ts_125401v040200p.pdf), 
The Cell identifier (C-Id) is used to uniquely identify a cell within an RNS. The Cell-Id together with the identifier of the controlling RNC (CRNC-Id) constitutes the UTRAN Cell Identity (UC-Id) and is used to identify the cell uniquely
within UTRAN.

`UC-Id = RNC-Id + C-Id`

The C-Id is defined by the operator, and set in the RNC via O&M. The C-Id is set in a Node B by its C-RNC.